# Corrupt link to tar in OS X (yosemite)

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-yosemite, tar

So, i was trying all kinds of solutions for "gnutar" on "yosemite" and now it seems i got the link messed up.

Running tar in terminal throws:

> tar command not found

EDIT: Sorry, SO did not let me post original text so i had to strip it down and therefore missing out my question.

Question is, how to restore tar in osx again, is it located elsewhere other than /usr/bin /usr/local/bin  since it is there i managed to mess it up

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the output of `which tar`? If it's nothing, you'll have to locate where the actual binary is because it isn't in your `PATH`. If the binary is actually not there you'll have to reinstall.

Comment: Sorry, updated post, question is how to restore tar again since i messed up symlinks in */bin folders :(
Luke, is that like installing entire OS x or is there a way to reinstall just tar ?

Comment: Do you make a backups with TimeMachine? Beside that `/usr/bin/tar` is a symlink to  `/usr/bin/bsdtar`. And if you want to install additional commandline tools then use homebrew or macports.

Comment: No backups with time machine :( Tho i have back up of my initial system, and just realized i have the /bin folders in that backup. Youre absolutely right, jsut checked the symlink in my backup and saw the bsdtar link :)) Gonna re-try to restore bsdtar from backup...

Comment: You really should avoid to restore from the initial system if you already applied some updates on the current one. In the worst case this will make your whole system unstable.

Comment: That did it !!!! PHEW!!! copied bsdtar from backup, placed into bin folder and relinked and tar is back up again. Thanks for pointing me to right direction :)

Comment: t.niese yah i am aware of that, the i've only installed 1 update since the backup so i hope tar was not one of those :P

Comment: You really should make Backups. Since TimeMachine there no excuse to not make backups on OS X - especially if you _play_ with your system  ;)